# Call public static method from ajax 'wpcf7_mail_sent' hook

Tags: ajax, hooks

I'm trying to call action from 'wpcf7_mail_sent' hook (form submitted from frontend from not logged in user). It's not working.
If I call same method from hook, that attached to 'save_post' hook - it works. I update post from admin panel.

Code samples:

plugin #1 (This part works)

```
function event_updated( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
/*
    $post_ID(int) - Post ID.
    $post(WP_Post) - Post object.
    $update(bool) - Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
*/
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if ( "event_post_type" != $post_type ) return;

    do_action('update_event_hook', $post_ID, $post);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'event_updated', 10, 3 );
```

plugin #1 (this part throws 500 error)

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'set_event_booked' );
function set_event_booked($contact_form) {
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $submission ) {
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $id = $posted_data['post-id'];
    $new_id = $posted_data['event-id'];

    $post = new \stdClass;
    $post->ID = intval($posted_data['post-id']);
    $post->post_type = 'event_post_type';

    update_post_meta($new_id, 'event_booked', 'on');
    try {
        do_action('update_event_hook', $id, $post);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        $log_message = 'Add reservaion ERROR: '. $error_message;
    }
}
```

plugin #2

```
class API_sync_class
{
    private static $options;

    public static function Init()
    {
        self::$options = get_option("api_sync");

        if (self::$options['use']) {

            add_action('update_event_hook', array('API_sync_class', 'AddEditReservation'), 10, 2);
        }
    }

    public static function AddEditReservation($post_id, $post)
    {
    API_sync_class::DebugToFile('AddEditReservation method:');

    $type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ($type && ($type != 'event_post_type')) {
        return;
    }

    $appdata = self::AppData($post);
    API_sync_class::DebugToFile('Data to be sent to API (prepared)');
    API_sync_class::DebugToFile($appdata);

        ....... Some other code of meethod
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
In my case there was 'PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_home_path()'.
Yup. That's simply.